# How to incorporate Wav2Lip in ReactJS

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, lipsync

I want to incorporate **Wav2Lip** (A Python package) into ReactJS using NodeJS, I found a package on NPM called [wav2lip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wav2lip) but its incompatible with ReactJS. I tried editing the webpack using craco but did not succeed. Do you guys know a way for me to use **Wav2Lip** in ReactJS?

Here is the code for `App.js` using **wav2lip** NPM package and the methods I tried for fixing it:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Wav2Lip from 'wav2lip';
import { remote } from 'electron';
import fs from 'fs-extra';

function App() {
  const [isProcessing, setIsProcessing] = useState(false);
  const [videoSrc, setVideoSrc] = useState('');

  const handleRun = async () => {
    setIsProcessing(true);

    const inputDir = remote.app.getAppPath();
    const outputDir = remote.app.getAppPath();
    const instance = new Wav2Lip({ inputDir, outputDir, fs });

    try {
      const result = await instance.Run('./game.mp4', './game.wav');
      setIsProcessing(false);
      setVideoSrc(result.outputFilePath);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setIsProcessing(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {isProcessing ? (
        <p>Processing...</p>
      ) : (
        <>
          {videoSrc && (
            <video controls>
              <source src={videoSrc} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
          )}
          <button onClick={handleRun}>Run Wav2Lip</button>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`craco.config.js` file

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const util = require("util");
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig) => {
      delete webpackConfig.node;
      webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
          },
        },
      });
      webpackConfig.plugins.push(
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          "process.env": {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
          },
        })
      );
      webpackConfig.resolve.fallback = {
        path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
        fs: false,
        child_process: false,
        crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
        stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        util: require.resolve("util"),
        assert: require.resolve("assert/"),
        constants: require.resolve("constants-browserify"),
      };
      return webpackConfig;
    },
    plugins: [],
  },
};
```

`package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "face",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^7.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "constants-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "electron": "^23.1.1",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "wav2lip": "^1.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2"
  }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is that related to the Python? You can not just use the library written for the other programming language. Moreover, it seems that Wav2lip for python, which is located in Python package index is some garbage package which is not actually related to wav2lip, as all the links to the code and docs are linking to other unrelated library

Comment: Oh, thanks for the feedback, this was just my attempt, I don't know how to make Wav2Lip  in Javascript (ReactJS). So if you have any methods please  inform me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a Python package from NodeJS, it seems.

1. Install `python-shell` using npm

   npm install python-shell
2. Write your script in python, for example `app.py` containing:

```
    import wav2lip
    
    def my_function(input_str):
        # Do some processing using the wav2lip package
        output_str = "Processed " + input_str
        return output_str
```

3. In your Node.js script, import the `python-shell` module and use it to spawn a Python process and call the function defined in the `app.py` script.

```
    const { PythonShell } = require('python-shell');
    
    // Set up the PythonShell object 
    let options = {
      mode: 'text',
      pythonPath: 'python', // Path to your Python executable
      pythonOptions: ['-u'], // Allows stdout to be displayed in real-time
      scriptPath: '.', // Path to the directory containing app.py
      args: ['input string'], // Arguments to pass to the function
    };
    
    PythonShell.run('app.py', options, function (err, results) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Output:', results[0]); 
    });
```

Comment: But how do I use it in react JS, I just get a bunch of errors about webpack.